# PHPExcel Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Formula Error: Unexpected ,'

Tags: exception, excel-formula, export-to-excel, average, phpexcel

I have searched on google but i could not find any solution for this.
What i'm trying to do is making a excel5 export file from a report with php.

Whenever i try to make a average of times i getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'myexcelsheet!F38 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,'
```

This is the formula that gives the error:

```
=SUM(F9:F36)/COUNTIF(F9:F36, "*" & "<>00:00:00" & "*")
```

The cell data types are Time. With a COUNT it works fine but it needs to ignore the 00:00:00 times.

This are the includes:

```
require_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
require_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php");
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell/AdvancedValueBinder.php';
```

Whole Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'myexcelsheet!F38 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,' in /path/to/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:293 Stack trace: #0 /path/to/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php(702): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() #1 /path/to/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php(295): PHPExcel_Worksheet->calculateColumnWidths() #2 /path/to/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(194): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5_Worksheet->close() #3 /path/to/rep-functions.php(985): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('/path/t...') #4 /path/to/report.php(462): export_excel(Array, Array, 'report.ph...', Array, Array, Array) #5 {main} thrown in /path/to/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 293
```

This is what i get from the testFormula function

```
Formula Value is=SUM(F9:F36)/COUNTIF(F9:F36,"*" & "00:00:00" & "*")  
Expected Value is UNKNOWN  
Parser Stack :-

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => F9
            [reference] => F9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => F36
            [reference] => F36
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => Binary Operator
            [value] => :
            [reference] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => Operand Count for Function SUM()
            [value] => 1
            [reference] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => Function
            [value] => SUM(
            [reference] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => F9
            [reference] => F9
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => F36
            [reference] => F36
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [type] => Binary Operator
            [value] => :
            [reference] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [type] => Value
            [value] => "*"
            [reference] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [type] => Value
            [value] => "00:00:00"
            [reference] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [type] => Binary Operator
            [value] => &
            [reference] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [type] => Value
            [value] => "*"
            [reference] => 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [type] => Binary Operator
            [value] => &
            [reference] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [type] => Operand Count for Function COUNTIF()
            [value] => 2
            [reference] => 
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [type] => Function
            [value] => COUNTIF(
            [reference] => 
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [type] => Binary Operator
            [value] => /
            [reference] => 
        )

)
CALCULATION ENGINE ERROR: Worksheet!F38 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,  
Evaluation Log:  
Array    
(  
)
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this function to debug the calculation engine:

```
function testFormula($sheet,$cell) {
    $formulaValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getValue();
    echo 'Formula Value is' , $formulaValue , PHP_EOL;
    $expectedValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getOldCalculatedValue();
    echo 'Expected Value is '  , ((!is_null($expectedValue)) ? $expectedValue : 'UNKNOWN') , PHP_EOL;


     PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->writeDebugLog = true;
    $calculate = false;
    try {
        $tokens = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->parseFormula($formulaValue,$sheet->getCell($cell));
        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo PHP_EOL;
        $calculate = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'PARSER ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

    if ($calculate) {
        try {
            $cellValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();
            echo 'Calculated Value is ' , $cellValue , PHP_EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
            print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->debugLog);
            echo PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'CALCULATION ENGINE ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
            print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->debugLog);
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass the worksheet object and the cell ID as arguments, and it generates detailed logs of how the lexer and parser evaluate the formula

Comment: I've added the function but i can not make something out of it.

Comment: The output is in the question.

Comment: SOrry, missed a line in the function

Comment: Oke thanks i think i have found the problem. [14] => Worksheet!F38 -> Evaluating COUNTIF( { 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569; 25569,000081019; 25569; 25569 }, ">25569" ) I see here that one value is 25569,000081019 (this value is 7 seconds later).

Comment: It also looks as though  25569,000081019 has a comma rather than a decimal point - US/UK format needed internally